# The picture on superuser "page not found" webpage, what is its origin?

Tags: support

This picture:

[image]

from here: https://superuser.com/404

What is the origin of this picture? I am just curious, I tried Bing Visual Search it and failed to find information relevant to its origin.

Its name is "it-kama-sutra.jpg", what does its name mean? What does this picture mean? Why was it selected by superuser.com?

Can anyone elaborate this to me? I think this is directly relevant to this site itself.

---

I have found something:

> We've all been there before -- you get home from the bars after
> striking out with the ladies but you're still feeling amorous. So what
> do you do? You bang your computer. Well thankfully this is not a
> picture of that. ***These are actually Kama Sutra positions to be used
> by trained IT professionals to mount a PC while attempting a
> repair.***

[source](https://geekologie.com/2008/05/it-kama-sutra-poses-threw-my-b.php)

And Kama Sutra on Wikipedia: [Kama Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kama_Sutra), I still don't have any idea how all of these are connected...

---

I can't get any more relevant information because I am behind the GFW, I am using Lantern and it automatically connects to South Korean servers, I don't get to choose which server to connect to because I am using the free version.

Now this is what Google says:

```
Inappropriate search results are removed for minors under 19. You can view normal search results if you are over 19.
```

<kbd>Verify your age for your Google Account</kbd>     Verify your age for this session

The problem being I can only choose numbers from Korean telecommunication companies, while my number is Chinese...

And I have also tried Bing, and I have found out BING really is abbreviation of `Bing Is Not Google` (pun intended), while Google is useless, Bing is even more useless, it even can't find a single result relevant to IT...

I am also able to use tor(not Tor Browser), however it is very slow, and often I have to complete ***multiple captchas*** to perform a single Google search...

By the way, I can still get many search results from Google even the search results are filtered, and none of them are relevant to Information Technology...

And about my age, I was born in Nineteen Ninety-Nine.

---

The link from the above citation source is dead, and this is the only Wayback Machine snapshot I can find:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140904013723/http://digg.com/comedy/Kama_Sutra_For_IT_People?OTC-nv

The link was already dead on September 4, 2014...

---

The latest snapshot of the link in question I am able to find that isn't dead is this:

https://web.archive.org/web/20100309001724/http://digg.com/comedy/Kama_Sutra_For_IT_People

Still have no idea whence this originated in and how this became 404 picture of superuser.com...

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites